# How to use Future<V> correctly?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

The below code is from a backing bean. `async()` is called from the view by `<f:event listener="#{nextBean.async}" type="preRenderView"/>`. As I do not want this operation to delay the view's rendering, it triggers an `@Asynchronous`-annotated method in an EJB returning a `Future<Boolean>`.
As long as this operation is running I want the UI blocked and so I execute a `<p:remoteCommand>` triggering `ready()` which checks if there is a result for the `Future`-Object which means the asynchronous method has finished and then unblocks the UI.
Problem: The asynchonous method seems to get called a second time by `ready()`. How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

the backing bean:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
@Getter
@Setter
public class NextBean {

    @EJB private AsyncBean asyncBean;
    private Future<Boolean> ready;

    public void async() {
        ready = asyncBean.async();
    }

    public void ready() {
        try {
            while (ready.get() != true) {
                Thread.sleep(300);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

The Facelets Code:

```
<html xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head></h:head>
<h:body id="wholeView">
    <f:metadata>
        <f:event listener="#{nextBean.async}" type="preRenderView"></f:event>
    </f:metadata>
        <p:blockUI id="blockui" block=":wholeView" widgetVar="blockUI">
            please wait
    </p:blockUI>
    <h:form>
    <p:remoteCommand onstart="blockUI.show();"
        name="doIt"
        id="dooo"
        process="@this"
        action="#{nextBean.ready}"
        oncomplete="blockUI.hide();"
        autoRun="true"
    />

    </h:form>
    CONTENT
</h:body>
</html>
```

The EJB:

```
package mypackage;

import java.util.concurrent.Future;

import javax.ejb.AsyncResult;
import javax.ejb.Asynchronous;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@Stateless
@Log
public class AsyncBean {

    @Asynchronous
    public Future<Boolean> async(){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            return new AsyncResult<Boolean>(true);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:**
1. The user is directed to the view from an external page (as part of a payment process).
2. With requesting the view business logic is supposed to be executed which shoould not delay the rendering of the view but block it's UI while the business logic is executed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, but this approach isn't making any sense.

1. The `preRenderView` event is fired on every HTTP request.

   - Opening the page for first time counts as one HTTP request.
   - `<p:remoteCommand autoRun="true">` counts as one HTTP request.

   So, effectively, when you just open this page, 2 HTTP requests are fired. This explains why the `preRenderView` listener method is invoked twice.
2. `@Asynchronous` is completely useless in this context. You're calling `Future#get()` in the very same thread as wherein you invoked the `@Asynchronous` method. You're not doing anything useful in between the call and the `Future#get()`. Basically, you're blocking the current thread and telling it to wait until the other thread is finished. The current thread is basically sitting doing nothing and not available for other tasks, which is a major waste. How does that make sense? Why not just doing the job in the current thread by removing `@Asynchronous`?

You didn't state the concrete functional requirement for which you thought that *this* would be the solution, so it's hard to give a suited answer or push you in the right direction. I guess that you need [push](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/push/index.jsf).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I updated my question and hope that this makes the functional requirements clearer. :)

Comment: I removed `<f:metadata>` and `<f:event>` and added a simple `#{nextBean.async()}` to the body and it seems I got the wanted result.

Comment: Can. Note that this is still synchronous. That `@Asynchronous` is then completely superfluous and only a waste of a whole thread. Also, you can just do the job in bean's (post)constructor if that method isn't returning anything useful for usage in HTML output.

Comment: OK, I am starting to get what you are saying... Thank you! :)